# Integration $\displaystyle\int \frac{x}{x^2-5x+6}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate the Integral:

> $$\int \frac{x}{x^2-5x+6}dx$$

I solved twice and once I got $$3\log\left|x-3\right|-2\log\left|x-2\right|+C$$ and I tried again and changed one step and I got $$-2\log\left|x-3\right|-3\log\left|x-2\right|+C$$

which one is correct? and why ?

Answer (score 3):

Convert Integrand to Partial fractions

> $$\frac{x}{x^2-5x+6}=\frac{3}{x-3}-\frac{2}{x-2}$$

$$\begin{align}I&=\int \frac{x}{x^2-5x+6}dx\\
&=\int\frac{3}{x-3}dx-\int\frac{2}{x-2}dx\\
&=3\ln|x-3|-2\ln|x-2|+C\\
\end{align}$$

Try again and I'm sure you'll get this!